# Android: Scaling image offsets between resolutions

Tags: android, imageview, margin

I have an app where, in landscape, I line up a bunch of lowercase alphabet ImageView pngs so that they are sitting on an imaginary line. The problem is that they are of different heights i.e. an 'h' is taller than an 'a'. Thus I've been setting the android:layout_marginTop attribute for each letter, in pixels, to line them up on the Galaxy Tab. This has worked.

My problem is that when I go to run the app on a Milestone, the scaling of the offsets is a litttttle wonky. It looks like there's some sort of scaling happening, which is kind of working, but it's not perfect. Anyone have an idea how I could remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that trying to hard code the offsets for each letter and each display resolution is going to be a real pain and will be even bigger pain to maintain.

An easy solution would be to use photoshop (or gimp) to resize the png files so they all have the exact same dimensions and set the new region of the PNG to be transparent.

Comment: I agree. I'm just translating this app for Android. In reality, there is a set of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and numbers / symbols. I was just given a whole bunch of PNGs and didn't want to have to go through them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would first question why you're doing it this way...seems overly complicated. That said, you could try to just measure the maximum heigh for the ImageViews and use that. For example, x, h, and g all have the same x-height (the height of the lowercase letter x) but the h has an ascender, and the g has a descender (which go above and below the standard x-height respectively). You could create all the letters aligned on the baseline, give them all the same height (the x-height + the ascender height + the descender height) and then just align top, bottom, or center align them on the imaginary line, which should give you a proper alignment.

Really, if you can share a little more information (a screenshot maybe?) there's probably a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree that it's overly complicated. Here's a snapshot of the letters on a Milestone. Uppercase: [link](http://tinyurl.com/3d47lvo) and lowercase: [link](http://tinyurl.com/3vp62qa). I was just given the PNGs as I'm converting the app to Android, from Apple. I could ask for the PNGs to be all resized so they have a constant height, but I wanted to try to see if there was a better way first.

Comment: You might look into just using a TextView. The letters aren't anything specialized; you could just use spanning styles to change the individual letter colors (I believe), and you can add a drop shadow to the TextView to match the shadow of the letters. It would actually look better as the letters would be vector vs raster, and in your preview shown, it appears the PNGs have some of the drop shadows cut off anyway. That'd be my suggestion, anyway.

Comment: good point, although, as I have it right now, all the letters are ImageViews, and when someone clicks on a letter, the respective letter appears on a chalkboard, which can be dragged around and what not. not sure how I would implement that with a textview...